# Printing a histogram

Tags: python, list, indexing, histogram, traceback

I have a list of integer percentages which I need to print using the following pattern:

> ```
> The index of a value, a tab (8 spaces), a '*' printed for each percentage point
> ```

also if the value for an index is 0, print 'less than 1 percent'

I have tried this code:

```
for b in new_tally:
    if b > 0:
        print new_tally[b], \t, '*' * b
    else:
        print 'Less than 1% of words had this length'
```

However I keep getting the error code: list index out of range.

I do not understand this at all, can someone point out what I have done wrong?

Comment: `print b-1, '*' * b`,  maybe?

Comment: if something fancy doesnt work for you, do it step by step.  just type b, or just print new_tally and see what you get.

Comment: you have to distinguish list index and content of list.  say if you have `lst = [5, 7, 8, 6, 4, 2]`.  `for b in lst: print b` is going to print lst's conteent, not index.  so you are going to get 8 for the thrird one.  you are using this 8 again as index for lst[b], then there is no such thing as 8th element of the list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the code you wanted was:

```
>>> new_tally = [5, 7, 8, 6, 4, 2]
>>> for i, b in enumerate(new_tally, 1):
        print i, ':', b, '*' * b

1 : 5 *****
2 : 7 *******
3 : 8 ********
4 : 6 ******
5 : 4 ****
6 : 2 **
```

The cause of the original traceback is that list members are looked up using square brackets instead of parentheses.  `new_tally(i)` is a function call.  `new_tally[i]` is an indexed lookup.

Comment: Instead of printing the value first then a corresponding number of *, how would you suggest editing it so that it prints the index + 1 of the value then the number of *. I would like to do this as then it would list the word length followed by the percentage points. This is because in my case the word length is always one more than the index as the indices start at and word length starts at 1. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Editted the example to show how to use ``enumerate()`` to index the bins starting from a count of one.

Answer (score 0):

```
for key,val in new_tally.iteritems():
    print('{k} {a}'.format(k=key,a='*'*int(val)))
```

or, if you want the histogram sorted in descending order of frequency:

```
import operator
for key,val in sorted(new_tally.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True):
    print('{k} {a}'.format(k=key,a='*'*int(val)))
```

Answer (score 0):

first piece:

```
new_tally = [5, 7, 8, 6, 4, 2]
for b in new_tally:
    print b
```

second piece:

```
new_tally = [5, 7, 8, 6, 4, 2]
for i in range(len(new_tally)):
    print i, new_tally[i]
```

the above two do approximately the same thing.  you are mixing up between visiting elements in sequence (first approach) versus accessing list elements by sequential index (second approach).